# How to handle a subcribe() method correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, reactivex

I've been having troubles with `subscribe()` method in my code (debug console's message below)

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

and I can't figure out how to make it right, there is my part of code where it starts

```
private fun startSearch(query: String) {
        disposables.addAll(IMyService.searchCourse(query)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe ({ courses ->
                adapter = CourseAdapter(baseContext, courses)
                recycler_search.adapter = adapter
            }, {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }))
    }

    private fun getAllCourses() {
        disposables.addAll(IMyService.coursesList
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe ({ courses ->
                adapter = CourseAdapter(baseContext, courses)
                recycler_search.adapter = adapter
            }, {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }))
    }
```

and there is the full [code](https://github.com/ladamengh/LoginregisterApp)

[parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51vVu.png)

Comment: Try using `onSuccess = {` and `onError = {` so you know what lambda you're passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reactive programming, passing a subscriber to an Observable should entail how to deal with three cases:

1. onSuccess
2. onError
3. onFailure

If however, you simply want to pass a subscriber which you know for sure will not have any errors or any failures and certain that it will always succeed, then simply try onSuccess or onFailure as mentioned by @EpicPandaForce. A good practice however is to always implement the three cases as you never know.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how I should implement it, because compiler is showing the right context already(I've added a screenshot of it)